# How to connect Fast Report frxdbdataset to fdquery

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac, fastreport

I have placed all of `frxReport`, `frxDBDataset`, `FDQuery` and `FDConnection` on my form, the `FDConnection` is correctly setup and `FDQuery` one is connected to it and `frxDBDataset` is connected to `FDQuery` but when is double click on `frxDBDataset` to see what's inside the database, it is empty (I can see all the tables and data in the data explorer).

Comment: Why not having consulted [the official samples](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDQuery)?

Answer (score -2):

I figured it out. You go to the FDQuery Component->properties->SQL : `SELECT * FROM TableName;`

You can also configure it in the code:

```
MDB.FDQuery1.SQL.Text :=
   'SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ID = :ID';
MDB.FDQuery1.ParamByName('ID').AsInteger := ID;
MDB.FDQuery1.Open;

frxDBDataset1.DataSet := MDB.FDQuery1;
```